# SQL INSERT gives "Invalid query: Unknown column"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to put into database a `$username`, but my query gives me `Invalid query: Unknown column ...`.

This is my query:

```
"INSERT INTO `user`(`screen_name`) VALUES (".$userName.")"
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please update your questions with more details. Table structure, complete error message, code,...
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post the structure of your user table, it sounds like there is no screen_name column in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no quotes at the string.

```
"INSERT INTO `user`(`screen_name`) VALUES ('".$userName."');"
```

Add the semi-colon at the end but it is not always necessary.

Comment: **Minor** improvement to above - add semi-colon as delimiter:
`"INSERT INTO \`user\`(\`screen_name\`) VALUES ('".$userName."');" `

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

Comment: I can understand the concept on this answer, but without any explanation of it, using this code *directly* won't work on OP's case.